# Security warning on Internet Explorer

Tags: error-messages

We are facing an issue with some of our users where whenever they login they are getting IE Security warning mixed content prompt. We have added salesforce in the trusted sites and have also enabled mixed-contents under IE settings but still the prompt is coming. Weird thing is when we login to sandbox and access same page we don't get this warning.

Has anyone came across such issue?

Comment: If you click "no" - which part of the page doesn't load? (I understand IE might be poor tool to debug it - what about Chrome? Should tell you which content source it didn't like). Maybe somebody added say sidebar component with some content loaded over plain HTTP? After logging in the users end up in standard application (home tab) or Service Cloud Console for example?

Comment: weird thing is it still loads the content even if i say 'no'

Comment: It should suppress pages & external scripts loaded insecurely, for example `http://maps.google.com` might fail to show the map nicely because SF is over HTTPs. Anything "http" in the network traffic tool or Javascript Console? F12 in IE, Ctrl+Shift+J in chrome & FF.

Comment: It probably isn't your site that is causing the issue, but another site that you reference. Maybe a CCS,Javascript, or image that your site references. So while your site might be trusted in IE the third party resource isn't.

Comment: but in that case behavior of sandbox and production should not be same, as its the same code in both the environment.